# ¿Es posible parar la ejecución del código en cliente hasta la finalización de onloadend

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

necesitaría que se ejecutase el código del reader.onloadend con su llamada ajax antes de continuar con la ejecución, este es mi código:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL($("#fuAdjuntos")[0].files[0]);
reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
        var base64reader = evt.target.result.split("base64,")[1];
        nameAdjunto = $('#fuAdjuntos')[0].files[0].name;
        msg = nameAdjunto;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Chat.aspx/SubirAdjunto',
            data: '{base64reader: "' + base64reader + '",idUsuario: "' + idUsuario + '",nameAdjunto: "' + nameAdjunto + '" }',
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
}

 msg = msg.replace("<", "< ");
 var userName = $('#hdUserName').val();
 var date = GetCurrentDateTime(new Date());
 var usuarioEnvio = usuarioChatSeleccionado;
 if ((usuarioEnvio == null || usuarioEnvio == '') && grupoDestinatarioChat == null) {
 chatHub.server.sendMessageToAll(userName, msg, date, idUsuario, $('#hdId').val(), null, esAdjunto);
                }
```

El problema es que continúa con la ejecución y finalmente ejecuta el contenido del evento reader.onloadend.

¿Sería posible? (He probado poniendo un "timer", pero al acabar sigue con la ejecución y deja para el final el reader).

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Realmente no... ¿qué es lo que quieres hacer? Seguro que hay una manera mejor de conseguir lo que intentas

Comment: continuar con cual ejecucion ? alli solo se visualiza el codigo del onloadend

Comment: He editado el código, me interesa que se ejecute antes el onloadend que el chatHub.server.sendMessageToAll.

Answer (score -1):

Me estaba liando un poco, se ha resuelto copiando ese código en el success de la llamada ajax y un else también para ese código. Gracias!!!

Comment: Danis, aunque sea tu propia pregunta, la respuesta ha de ser como si fuera para otro usuario. Has de mostrar la explicacion detallada y el codigo resultante. Un saludo

Comment: Es válido responder tu propia pregunta, pero la respuesta debe ser completa. Por favor lee [answer]. Un saludo.